# Can Genymotion used with Katalon

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, katalon-studio

Currently we are using Android emulator by Android Studio along with Katalon. Most of the time the app crashes. We are looking to buy Genymotion but before that we want to make sure it works with Katalon. When I googled it, I saw a old post on 2018 that Katalon won't support Genymotion. What about now?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried Katalon Studio yet, but Genymotion Desktop virtual devices usually show up as real devices to other tools. So it should work.

The easiest way to make sure it works for you is to give a try. For the best performances, you can download the latest beta from https://www.genymotion.com/download-beta/.

Comment: Copy'n'paste from a 2017 answer : https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-can-use-genymotion-in-mobile-testing/6742/4